# R: Can you create a custom hierarchy order for date time data?

Tags: r, date, hierarchy

In the R programming language, can you create a custom order? For example, I'm trying to organize a column of dates. Is there a way to tell R that the hierarchy is Sun > Mon > Tues > Wed ...?

**Edit**:

My column entries for the TimeStamp column look like this: "Mon Sep 26 13:32:17 PDT 2011".

`str(myDataset)` gives me:

```
str(d$TimeStamp)
```

> Factor w/ 21905 levels "Fri Dec 02 01:09:38 PST
>   2011",..: 6022 6026 6031 6034 6043 6046 6050 6055 6065 6069 ..."

My goal is to organize them in chronological order. Does that explain the situation better?

Comment: I've moved your comments into your question for you. That way the question actually reflects the problem you're having. If you feel I've misconstrued your intent, feel free to improve the edits or roll them back.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use `ordered`.

```
ordered(c("mon","sun","mon","tue","sun"), levels=c("sun","mon","tue"))
#[1] mon sun mon tue sun
#Levels: sun < mon < tue
```

Now, to turn your specific "column of dates" into an ordered factor, it would help to know which date your using...

```
# try this on your data and post the result...
str(myDataset)
```

Here's one way if your dates are of class "Date" (or whatever `weekdays` accepts):

```
d <- data.frame(Id=1:10, StartDate=as.Date(1001:1010.5, origin="1970-01-01"))
d <- within(d, StartDay<-ordered(weekdays(StartDate, TRUE), levels=c("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat")))
d
str(d)
```

**UPDATE** Or do you simply want to sort by date?! Because if the dates span multiple weeks, I don't see how it is meaningful to sort by weekdays?

```
d[order(d$StartDate), ]
```

**Second update** The `as.Date` function takes a `format` argument. There you can specify your specific format. Unfortunately `%Z` (timezones) doesn't work with `as.Date`, so I hard-coded it to "PST".

```
x <- as.Date(d$StartDate, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S PST %Y")
d[order(x, ]
```

Comment: Thanks guys. My column entries for the TimeStamp column look like this: "Mon Sep 26 13:32:17 PDT 2011". Str(myDataset) gives me: "> str(d$TimeStamp)
 Factor w/ 21905 levels "Fri Dec 02 01:09:38 PST 2011",..: 6022 6026 6031 6034 6043 6046 6050 6055 6065 6069 ...".

My goal is to organize them in chronological order. Does that explain the situation better?

Comment: @user1107035 Then they should be converted to an actual datetime format, rather than a factor.  Something like `as.POSIXct(as.character(d$TimeStamp))` would probably work.  Datetimes naturally sort chronologically.

Comment: Thanks much. How do I convert those times to an actual datetime format? I tried your as.POSIX... but it says "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format". 

Tommy, yes you are correct. I just want them chronologically ordered.

Comment: The reason `%Z` doesn't work for input is that the codes aren't unique (and hence ambiguous).  E.g., `CST` can be China Standard Time or Cuba Standard Time or Australian Central Standard Time or North American Central Standard Time or Central American Central Standard Time.

Comment: If you need to include the time zone, do `stringr::str_replace(d$Timestamp, "PDT", "-0700")` and include `%z` in the format string.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for ordered factor levels.  For instance:

```
# Create vector of days
day <- c("Sun", "Mon", "Sun", "Tue", "Wed")

# Make that vector factors (not required--only for illustrating factors)
day.f <- factor(day)

# Define the order of factor levels
days.order <- ordered(day.f, levels = c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
"Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"))

days.order
#[1] Sun Mon Sun Tue Wed
#Levels: Sun < Mon < Tue < Wed < Thu < Fri < Sat
```

Now, if you have a column `col` in your dataframe `df` of three-letter day-of-week data, you could define ordered levels the same way:

```
df$col <- ordered(df$col, levels = c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
"Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"))
```

This page provides more useful information about working with factors and ordered levels:
http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/R/modules/factor_variables.htm